# execute script on remote using curl

Tags: curl

I uploaded a file `script.cmd` to a Windows FTP server via `curl`.

No I'd like to execute this script on the remote server via curl.
When I just do this:

```
curl <FTPURL> -Q 'call ./path/to/my/script.cmd'
```

then I get a `500 Command not understood`.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run a command/script via ftp (at least not that I've ever seen). If you have a web server on the same box or you use curl to call the script via http(s) or you can write a script that ssh's into the box and executes the command, see [Ssh and run command upon connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481982/ssh-and-run-command-upon-connection) in another question for help.